# Defining variable in PHP

Tags: php, html

So I've been trying to understand some of this PHP/HTML code I came over but it doesn't work at all, what am I missing?

```
<?php 
$page = 'Start';

include 'themes/battlefield4/header.php';
?>

<h1><?php $page ?></h1>

<?php
include 'themes/battlefield4/footer.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to `echo` or `print` any output

```
<h1><?php echo $page ?></h1>
```

Comment: You should also add a semicolon: `<h1><?php echo $page; ?></h1>`

Comment: Actually, because it's a self contained block (has a closing tag), it's optional here

Comment: True, but still, best practices and such.